# Use a text file stored in ASSETS folder

Tags: java, android, assets

I'm trying to understand the difference between data files stored in the assets folder and those stored in the res/raw folder.  My goal is to have a data file stored in the app directory structure where (in this case) test scores are stored, they can be accessed and then they can be modified.  It is my understanding that I need to use an ASSET instead of RAW file for this.

I managed to load up the data from the text file into an array when the text file was stored in the RES/RAW folder but I can't make it work now that I'm using an ASSET file.  I thought it was as easy as using AssetManager.open.

Ultimately my one question is this.  How do I read and write to a text file in the ASSET folder?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[][] testScoreList = new String[3][3];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Load test scores into arraylist
        nameArrayListMethod();
    }

   //This method loads test scores into an array
    public void nameArrayListMethod (){
        InputStreamReader InputSR = null;
        BufferedReader BufferedRdr = null;
        String thisLine = null;

        AssetManager am = getAssets();

        InputSR = new InputStreamReader(am.open("test_scores.txt"));
        BufferedRdr = new BufferedReader(InputSR);


        try {
            // open input stream test_scores for reading purpose.
            int i = 0;
            while ((thisLine = BufferedRdr.readLine()) != null) {
                // System.out.println(thisLine);

                String[] parts = thisLine.split(" ");
                testScoreList[i][0] = parts[0];
                testScoreList[i][1] = parts[1];
                i = i +1;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

I'm getting an `Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException` eror on the `(am.open("test_scores.txt"))` line.

Cheers for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AssetManger#open(String) will throw exception and you need handle it.

```
public final InputStream open(String fileName) throws IOException {
    return open(fileName, ACCESS_STREAMING);
}
```

So you need:

```
   try {
        InputSR = new InputStreamReader(am.open("test_scores.txt"));
        BufferedRdr = new BufferedReader(InputSR);
        // open input stream test_scores for reading purpose.
        int i = 0;
        while ((thisLine = BufferedRdr.readLine()) != null) {
            // System.out.println(thisLine);

            String[] parts = thisLine.split(" ");
            testScoreList[i][0] = parts[0];
            testScoreList[i][1] = parts[1];
            i = i +1;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: Why does it throw an exception? The file test_scores.txt does exist.  Your solution works by the way but I don't understand why.

Comment: It does not throw an exception, but it might due to unforeseen things. Reading and writing stuff being one of those more risky things. When talking to a server it becomes worse...

Answer (score 1):

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourTxtFile);
String s = IOUtils.toString(is); // Here is the whole string you want
IOUtils.closeQuietly(is); // don't forget to close your streams
```

Comment: Except my file is in the assets folder not the resource raw folder.  I needed to work in assets so that I can save and modify the file on the users device.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use try / catch to keep your app from crashing. They are there for a reason.

This is how I open files within Android:

```
try {
    InputStream inputstream = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIndentifier("file_name", "folder", getPackageName()));
    BufferedReader bufferedRdr = new BufferedReader(inputstream);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace(); // error handling should be better then this...
} // and you should close the InputStream and BufferedReader with .close().
```

Comment: Well if you work with the R.raw reference like David suggested the chance of getting IOException are very low

Comment: It is a good way to use the R.raw. Might be programmer pref. how and when to handle the low chances for Exceptions. I try to handle them, so the app does not crash without any apparent reason. But that is an other discussion ;)

Comment: I'm not using the file in R.raw.  The file I need to access is in assets folder.  It was my understanding that I needed to use the assest folder instead of the raw folder to allow the user to update and save the data file.

Comment: Well, you might not need to worry about that. You can use private files only your app can see... https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("myfile.txt")));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {    
    }
```